# How to make the gradient for a negative in triplet loss move ortogonal to the anchor and positive?

Tags: vector-spaces, orthogonality, gradient-descent

So i've implemented a convolutional neural network in C++ and I'm playing around with loss functions and gradient calculations. The network outputs the f(a), f(p) and f(n) of the last layer, which is a vector of 10 feature embeddings. They are all L2 normalized before they are used in the loss or gradient calculation.

I've tried different methods for loss and gradients and currently i use the one from this https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.11307 paper. The gradients are weighted accordingly as listed down below.

[Loss and gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5zSu.png)

Since, I've stumbled upon a gradient update method that makes the updating gradient of the negative move orthogonally to the anchor and positive movement. It's described in this paper. https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content_CVPR_2020/papers/Mohan_Moving_in_the_Right_Direction_A_Regularization_for_Deep_Metric_CVPR_2020_paper.pdf

The loss and gradient updating is shown below

[Gradient update with orthogonal movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0fRi.png)

The following paper reviews the different approaches to loss and gradient update functions and suggests that the cosine space is better to allow more difference between anchor and positive pairs: https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.11307.

The above gradient updating is defined in terms of euclidian space, I'm trying to wrap my head around how to implement the orthogonal movement of the negative gradient. I might be to bad at math to ever do it, can anyone help me out?